# ArrayList<Object<ArrayList<Object>>>

Tags: java, object, arraylist

im trying to place in my Arraylist an Object with an ArrayList Object but it doesnt work here is my Code.
I get the fault Error: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: for my LINE

> mi.get(i).comments.add(new komments());

It should work cause i=0  and mi.get(i) should exists

```
ArrayList<dateiles> mi = new ArrayList<dateiles>();

try {
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BE");
    int i = 0;

    while (rs.next()) {

        mi.add(new dateiles());
        mi.get(i).be = rs.getString("BEBE");
        mi.get(i).name = rs.getString("BEBENAME");

        mi.get(i).besid = rs.getInt("BEID");

        /**
         *
         * kommentsquery
         *
         */
        st2 = con.createStatement();
        rs2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE BEID='" + mi.get(i).besid + "' ");
        int i2 = 0;
        while (rs2.next()) {
            mi.get(i).comments.add(new komments());
            mi.get(i).comments.get(i2).name = rs2.getString("ONAME");
            mi.get(i).comments.get(i2).comment = rs2.getString("COMMENT");
            i2++;
        }

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Have you initialized `comments`?

Comment: wow thanks i made a misspelling !

Comment: `ArrayList<Object<ArrayList<Object>>>` is not valid Java because `Object` is not generic so you can't have `Object<anything>`. Do you mean `ArrayList<<ArrayList<Object>>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `dateiles.comments` is not initialized therefore it has the default `null` value when you try to call `add()`...